# How can i fix this message: warning require_once failed to open stream?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, grocery-crud

i have installed codeigniter and grocery crud, i got it to show my database, then all of a sudden i get this message:

```
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc_tables\config/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc_tables\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 70

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc_tables\config/constants.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc_tables\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 70
```

how can i fix this problem? what does it mean? thank you

Comment: By going to `C:\xampp\htdocs` and checking what the actual file path is.

Comment: Here your path is wrong `C:\xampp\htdocs\stlc_tables\config/constants.php`. You use `FCPATH` in CI

Comment: i am a newbie how would i do this?

Comment: @excelsiorone add your code where you use `require_once` ??

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew looks good thx

Answer (score 0):

> what does it mean?

It means that a file you try to load to your script does not exist. Loading the file with require or require_once results with a Fatal error in case the file is not found (opposed to include include_once).

> how can i fix this problem?

By making sure the given file exists in a given location and is readable.